# After loading from json file, all scriptableobjects in main scriptableobject are none

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an scriptable object script for my inventory, which saves some goods there. Goods are scriptable objects too and they are not changing.

Inventory script:

```cs
public class InventoryList : ScriptableObject 
{
    public List<KeyObject> keys;
    public List<HealthPotion> healingGoods;
    public List<ScrollObject> scrolls;

    private string path {
        get { return Application.persistentDataPath + @"/Inventory.IO"; }
    } 

    public void Save() {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    public void Load() {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, this);
    }
}
```

Healing potion script:

```
public class HealthPotion : ScriptableObject, IItemsCollect 
{
    [SerializeField] private InventoryList InventoryList;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite Sprite;
    [SerializeField] private string Description;
    [SerializeField] private int Cost = 200;
    private bool willdestroy { get; set; }

    bool IItemsCollect.DestroyOnUse => willdestroy;
    string IItemsCollect.Description => Description;
    int IItemsCollect.Cost => Cost;
    Sprite IItemsCollect.Sprite => Sprite;

    public void AddToInventoryList() {
        InventoryList.healingGoods.Add(this);
        InventoryList.Save();
    }

    public void Use(SpiritController spiritController, ControllerCanvas controllerCanvas) {
        willdestroy = spiritController.HealthAdd();
        if (willdestroy) {
            InventoryList.healingGoods.Remove(this);
            InventoryList.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Key script:

```
public class KeyObject : ScriptableObject, IItemsCollect 
{
    [SerializeField] private InventoryList InventoryList;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite Sprite;
    [SerializeField] private string Description;
    [SerializeField] private int Cost = 400;

    public string KeyCode;

    bool IItemsCollect.DestroyOnUse => false;
    string IItemsCollect.Description => Description;
    int IItemsCollect.Cost => Cost;
    Sprite IItemsCollect.Sprite => Sprite;

    public void AddToInventoryList() {
        if (!InventoryList.keys.Contains(this)) {
            InventoryList.keys.Add(this);
            InventoryList.Save();
        }
    }

    public void Use(SpiritController spiritController, ControllerCanvas controllerCanvas) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Scroll script:

```
public class ScrollObject : ScriptableObject, IItemsCollect 
{
    [SerializeField] private InventoryList InventoryList;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite Sprite;
    [SerializeField] private string Description;
    [SerializeField] private int Cost = 400;

    public string Text;
    public Sprite SpriteForScroll;

    bool IItemsCollect.DestroyOnUse => false;
    string IItemsCollect.Description => Description;
    int IItemsCollect.Cost => Cost;
    Sprite IItemsCollect.Sprite => Sprite;

    public void AddToInventoryList() {
        if (!InventoryList.scrolls.Contains(this)) {
            InventoryList.scrolls.Add(this);
            InventoryList.Save();
        }
    }

    public void Use(SpiritController spiritController, ControllerCanvas controllerCanvas) {
        if (SpriteForScroll != null) controllerCanvas.ShowScrollAndImage(SpriteForScroll);
        else controllerCanvas.ShowScrollAndText(Text);
    }
}
```

After the save I have this:
[image]

But if I restart Unity and reload the inventory scriptableobject, I will have this:
[image]

Am I save something wrong? My version of unity is 2020.2.2f.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried using PlayerPrefs?

Comment: You can't (de)serialize `UnityEngine.Object` references! You could you provide more details about what exactly `KeyObject`, `HealthPotion` and `ScrollObject` are exactly and why they need to be ScriptableObjects?

Comment: Hello. I tried to use PlayerPrefs, but I need to save a lot data which is easier with scriptable objects

Comment: I have updated the question and add another scripts. They need to be scriptable objects, so I could save them during the game.

Comment: I think the answer will be in the json file that you're saving and loading.

Comment: json data shows the same string after saving and after loading  
`{"keys":[],"healingGoods":[],"scrolls":[{"instanceID":32862}]}`